# Cannot pass collection to method

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, .net-core

I have method that receieve `IList<IItemWithRules>`

Here is method

```
  public Dictionary<IItemWithRules, bool> CheckAvailability(IList<IItemWithRules> tiles)
    {
         **************
    }
```

Than I I try to call it and send as parameter List of `Tile`

Here is tile model

```
       public class Tile : NamedDomainObject, IItemWithRules
    {
        private int number;
        private string tooltip;
        private string link;
        private TileGroup group;
        private bool isNew;
        private Icon icon;
        private Ruleset availabilityRules;
    
        [CustomSerialization(CustomSerializationMode.Ignore, DTORole.Client)]
        public virtual int Number
        {
            get { return this.number; }
            set { this.number = value; }
        }
    
        public virtual string Tooltip
        {
            get { return this.tooltip.TrimNull(); }
            set { this.tooltip = value; }
        }
}
```

As you see I inherited same interface

But when I send it like this

```
 private IList<UserTile> ApplyRules(Employee employee, IList<Tile> tiles)
    {
        var activeTiles = tiles.Where(z => z.Active).ToList(); // Make sure all tiles are active. We don't need a strategy for this

        // Filter visible tiles
        var visibleTiles = this.rulesService.FilterItemsWithRules(activeTiles);

        var tilesAvailability = this.networkAvailabilityService.CheckAvailability(visibleTiles);

        // Store specific tile info to UserTile
        return visibleTiles.Select(t => new UserTile(t, tilesAvailability[t])).ToList();
    }
```

In this row  `var tilesAvailability = this.networkAvailabilityService.CheckAvailability(visibleTiles);`
I got error

> Argument type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<Home.Domain.Tile>' is not assignable to parameter type 'System.Collections.Generic.IList<Home.Domain.IItemWithRules>'

How I can pass it correctly?

Comment: What does `FilterItemsWithRules` return?

Comment: @vc74 it returns `List<Tile>`

Comment: You can only use inheritance in generics parameters with covariance or contravariance. In other case Generic<IFace> and Generic<Implementation> are different classes not connected, beside being concrete type of the same generic

Comment: @Selvin I can make `List<IItemWithRules> tiles` as parameter instead of `IList<IItemWithRules>` and than write code like this `var tilesAvailability = this.networkAvailabilityService.CheckAvailability(new List<IItemWithRules>(visibleTiles));`

Comment: Yeah, this is a genetic variance issue, but I would question whether you actually need an interface as specific as `IList`. Would `IReadOnlyList<UserTile>` suffice? `IReadOnlyList<out T>` is generically covariant.

Comment: You can try to make CheckAvailability parameterized with T with constraint

Answer (score 0):

`List<Tile>` is not assignable to `List<IItemWithRules>`, even though `Tile` derives from `IItemWithRules`. You have to cast it:

```
return visibleTiles.Select(t => (IITemWithRules)new UserTile(t, tilesAvailability[t])).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

if possible let `this.rulesService.FilterItemsWithRules` return `IList<IItemWithRules>` (i would prefer this, or you should rename it to `FilterTilesWithRules`)
else you will have to cast `visibleTiles` in any way:

```
visibleTiles.OfType<IItemWithRules>().ToList() // or
visibleTiles.Cast<IItemWithRules>().ToList() // or
new List<IItemWithRules>(visibleTiles) // like you suggested in comments
```

in case you need `visibleTiles` typed as IList of Tile you can change `CheckAvailability`-Signatur to something like this (like suggest by [slevin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/690952/selvin)):

```
public Dictionary<T, bool> CheckAvailability(IList<T> items) where T : IItemWithRules
{
     **************
}
```